# How to write good code in php?

Tags: php, optimization

I have to program a currency converter in php, which converts the following currencys:

```
EUR -> USD
EUR -> GBP
```

The code must have a good structure and clear. My code looks like this:

In index.php, I write the html inputs as follow:

```
                <select name="fT">
                    <option value="euro-usd@EUR-USD">EUR -> USD</option>
                    <option value="euro-gbp@EUR-GBP">EUR -> GBP</option>
                <select>
                   <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="">
                   <input type="submit"/>
```

convert.php looks like this:

```
<?php
include ("functions.php");
$fT = $_POST['fT'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$valueAndText = explode('@', $fromTo);
$fromTo = $valueAndText[0];
$text = explode('-', $valueAndText[1]);
$from = $text[0];
$to = $text[1];

echo convertCurr($fT, $amount) ;
?>
```

Any suggestion for improving this code?

Comment: You have hard-coded $currentSharePrices in script. Try putting them in config.php file.

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Leigh: Thanks for your comment, but do me a favor, by the way you improve how you speak.

Comment: @Vic: Yes i have little experience with PHP, this is why I ask for help here. Now can you please answer my question, instead of personal opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the share prices in a config file that you can replace with each change. I am considering that you do want to store the data in files and not in a DB.

The config file can look like:

```
<?php
 $config['usd-eur']=1.2;
 $config['usd-gbp']=0.5;
?>
```

Name this file as config.php,and place it with you scripts then include it.

```
<?php
 require_once('config.php');
?>
```

Regarding the $_POST variables you need to escape them to protect yourself from MySQL and XSS attacks.

You can use this function:

```
<?php
function filter($data) {
$data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    $data = stripslashes($data);

$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

return $data;
}?>
```

Then loop through your POST variables:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
 $mydata[$key] = filter($value);
}
```

Once more thing is the amount of processing you perform to detect the selection for the $fromto variable.

Why not to do it like that:

```
<select name="fromTo">
  <option value="1">(EUR) ---> (USD)</option>
  <option value="2">(EUR) ---> (GBP)</option>
</select>
```

Then perform a Switch-Case statement

```
<?php
 switch($mydata['fromTo']){
  case 1:
   $from='euro';
   $to='usd';
   break;
  case 2:
   $from='euro';
   $to='gbp';
   break;
 }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove all hard codes from our projects.
Moves them to a config file and include them in your project.So that you can change them any time without no modifications in the coading part. 
Use meaning full variable names and dont make them too big.
Try to add small comments which will explain the codes  or make under stand the codes more easly By another person
The main thing we have to look  is 
 
  **MAKE CODE READABLE**